# imwheel refuses to "window spread"

Tags: unity, mouse, shortcut-keys

currently I have my `~/.imwheelrc`

```
".*"
, Thumb1, Super_L|w
```

`Super_L|w` from the keyboard works and invokes the window spread.  But in imwheel it just prints the letter "w".  I tried      `, Thumb1, Super_L|a` and imwheel correctly invoked the expo.

I even tried remapping the window spread to `Alt_L|Shift_L|w` and that didn't work.  I tried it on `Thumb2` with no luck.  imwheel just refuses to invoke the window spread.

Does anyone one have any ideas why or an alternative solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cleaner solution than the original I was having problems with.

Instead of using imwheel..  I used CompizConfig Settings Manager

under `Window Management` -> `Scale` -> `Bindings` -> `Initiate Window Picker` (with the mouse icon).  For my case I wanted the first thumb button which was `button8`.  Done.